# How to convert String to float in DataStage 7.5 Server

Tags: datastage

How to convert String/Char into float in server DS 7.5.

Comment: Does DFloatToStringNoExp(DSLink2.FLOAT2DECI,6) work in 7.5? http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?t=92696&highlight=DecimalToString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DS 7.5, don't have the conversion options like DS 8.X , in 7.5, you just need to map the field, for Example, if in input it is string and in o/p it is float, then you just need to map the input to the output field. Sever will convert the string into float.